# what is # when importing module requires

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am seeing sometimes the modules modules being imported as `import A = from '#a'`. what does # means and what difference does it make compare with standard import

Comment: Can you give an example project/tutorial that you have seen that?

Comment: Hi @KonradLinkowski - after doing some research, I turned out to be es module and not commonjs. so it looks like this import {Users} from '#users'

Comment: I still would like to see a live example somewhere, because I didn't see syntax like that.

Comment: It could also be a webpack alias. `#` is often used as a prefix in aliases.